# refresh page on function call javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have a script where I am uploading a file to cloudinary, and then when it uploads, call my nodejs function (through js on front-end) and then update the file in my db. its working, but when I call the function, it does not render the page again. Instead nothing happens, but my db updates:

front-end script:

```
 <script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
                 
                <script type="text/javascript">  
                var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
                  cloudName: 'ps', 
                  uploadPreset: 'ld3l7evv'}, (error, result) => { 
                    if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
                      console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
                      console.log(result.info.secure_url)
                      var result_url = result.info.secure_url;
                      console.log("result url is " + result_url)
                      document.getElementById("url").value = result_url;
                      var employee_num = document.getElementById('employee_num').value
                      fetch('/changeProfileImage', {
                            method: 'POST', 
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                result_url,
                                employee_num
                            })
                        })
                    }
                  }
                )
```

backend (node.js):

```
  app.post('/changeProfileImage', (req, res) => {
  var employee_num = req.body.employee_num;
  var url = req.body.result_url;
  console.log("e " + employee_num)
  console.log("u " + url)
  
  var changeProfileImage = "update EMPLOYEES set (PROFILE_IMAGE)= '" + url + "' where EMPLOYEE_NUM = '" + employee_num + "'";
  ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(changeProfileImage, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      
      console.log("succes")

      conn.close(function () {
    // console.log("closed the function /index");
     });
  })
})
})
```

but it is not actually refreshing / reloading the page after it updates the db. any idea?

Comment: Why do you expect the page to refresh?

Comment: When you use AJAX, the page isn't reloaded automatically.

Comment: I don't expect to reload the page automatically, I want it to go into my function and redirect to the other function. I actually missed it in there, but under ` console.log("succes")` I have a `res.redrect('/account')` and it doesn't perform that function

Comment: I don't use node.js, but I'm pretty sure `res.redirect` will only redirect a web page, not AJAX. When you use AJAX, you need to do the redirection in the client's JavaScript.